# Swapping floor outlet covers

Tags: receptacle

I recently moved into a new place, and the previous owners have regular, rectangular white outlet covers on outlets in the floor - like you would find on any standard wall. I am not particularly handy, so I'm not sure what these are called.

It seems like it would be a good idea to replace these with actual floor outlet covers so nothing gets in the outlet / the covers themselves don't break. I'm curious if I can purchase an outlet cover that doesn't require me to do any electrical work? Like simply swap out the rectangular wall one with one meant for the floor. It doesn't matter if it's slightly raised over the floor. I'm having trouble finding anything like this - it seems like I need to get someone to re-wire the outlet itself for a proper floor cover. Any ideas?

Comment: The best solutions -- the ones used in offices -- require cutting a pocket in the floor so a cover (or an entire box) designed for this application can be installed flush with the floor surface. Moderately straightforward job for a pro (or contractor team) that has the right woodworking and basic electrical skills. I've been tempted to install one of these in my living room.

Comment: The search term you're looking for is "flush mount floor outlet"

Comment: An outlet in the floor is a hazard, unless sealed. Consider what could happen were a liquid to get in it, such as using a wet-mop or from a spilled drink. A standard outlet cover also could not take the weight of an adult or heavy furniture. See https://www.amazon.com/Enerlites-Diameter-Receptacle-Compatible-975509-C/dp/B00O19F41Q/ref=sr_1_40 for an example of a domed cover, or search on "flush floor electrical outlet".